# Why does Java's BitSet internally store long array but use int for set method?

Tags: java, bit, long-integer, bitset

According to the `BitSet` implementation, it internally uses an array of longs:

```
/**
 * The internal field corresponding to the serialField "bits".
 */
private long[] words;
```

But for the `set` method it uses int:

```
public void set(int bitIndex) {...}
```

So basically we can store `(2^31 - 1) * 64 * 8 = 2,147,483,642 * 64 * 8 = 137,438,953,088 bits`, but using `int` indexing we have access only to the first `2,147,483,648` bits.

Which means that `137,438,953,088 - 2,147,483,648 = 135,291,469,440` bits are unavailable.

But if developers of this class used `long` instead of `int` for bits indexing, it would solve all the problems, since with `long` we can navigate trough `2^63 - 1 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 bits`

It does not make any sense even from performance point of view.

What the reasoning behind the logic of using `int` instead of `long` for indexing and missing billions of bits?

P.S. One can say that the problem is `2 GiB` of heap size, but today it is not an issue anymore.

Comment: There's a difference between an array of `long`s and using an `int` for an index on said array.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca we do not indexing the array.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You are wrong. We do not need to have ints. Here is how it suppose to be: `void setBit(long bitIndex) {  int bucketIndex = (int) (bitIndex >> 6);  int indexInBucket = (int) (bitIndex % 64);
  words[bucketIndex] |= (1 << indexInBucket);}`

Comment: @harold this question via your link is about why we use `long[]` instead of `int[]` to **store data**. My question why we use `int` instead long to **navigate** through bitset indexes.

Comment: Probably because the authors of the class deemed it sufficient to have an upper limit of 2^31 indexable bits (in accordance with array indices, which are also limited to the integer range). If you need to store more than that number of individual bits, you could still write your own `BigBitSet` implementation, using not a `long[]` but a `long[][]`, which would allow addressing up to 2^63 individual bits.

Comment: I’m having trouble imagining a use case where 2³¹−1 bits is not large enough, but 2³⁷−1 is.

Comment: @NoNameQA I know, but try to understand the reasoning. If the design goal of BitSet was maximizing the maximum size, then `long[]` would have been used for that reason, and `long` would have been used for the index. But since that *wasn't* the reason `long[]` was used for the data, that reason *also* does not apply to the type of the index, and there was no reason to use `long` for the index.

Comment: @harold you just say what I said in my original question. My point is **what the reasoning** behind this logic. For now, it’s looks like some old quirky feature that developers did not fix yet.

Comment: @ThomasKläger `long[]` array contains `64 * 8 * 2^31 - 1` unique bits. If you replace `int` index to `long` index you will be able to navigate through `2^63 - 1` bits in `long[]` array. In other word you could set or get every bit in the bitset. But now you can navigate only `2^31 - 1` of `64 * 8 * 2^31-1`. It does not make any sense. Even from a performance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) states:

> The bits of a `BitSet` are indexed by nonnegative integers.

This is what it is supposed to do, so no `long` indexes needed.

That it's internal data structure could support more than 2^31 individual bits is an implementation detail that has no relevance for the public interface of the class (they could have used a `boolean[]` array and the class would still work, albeit with a bigger memory footprint and more runtime for some methods.)

---

The question remains: will the public interface of this class change to support `long` indexes?

This is highly unlikely, because supporting `long` indexes would mean that methods like

- `int cardinality()`
- `int nextClearBit()` (and similar methods: next/previous clear/set bit)
- `int size()`
- `IntStream stream()`

would also need to be changed, which would break existing code.

The only way I can think of a `BitSet` like class with `long` indexes would be an additional class `BigBitSet` (or `LongBitSet` or whatever you like) so that people **needing** bitsets with more then 2^31 bits could switch to that new class.

Whether such a class would ever be added to the `java.util` package is another question - for that you would have to convince the JCP executive board that this is a important addition / gaping hole in the current Java ecosystem.

Answer (score -1):

Each chunk of 64 bits is packed into long, not one long per bit index, so length of the long[] words array will use up to 268,435,456 bytes with int index when calling set(2147483647) or just one long if calling only bitset.set(1). Example in jshell:

```
BitSet b = new BitSet();
b.size();
==> 64 (ie words is length 1 can store 64 bits)
b.set(1);
b.size();
==> 64 (ie words is still length 1)
b.set(64)
==> 128 (ie words array is length 2, can store up to 128 bits)
```

Answer (score -2):

Usually you use bit sets to index into something else. Let’s say you use this bitset to index into an array.

```
BitSet b = new BitSet();
b.set(2147483647);
ArrayList<X> items = new ArrayList<X>();
// ...add a looot of elements to the ArrayList...
// then:
X item = items.get(b.nextSetBit(0));
```

To make this work, the array list must contain 2,147,483,648 elements, and it would at least use 2GB of RAM (assuming each element requires at least 1 byte of storage), which would crash Java.

Comment: *assuming each element requires at least 1 byte of storage*: Sorry, but that is wrong. `BitSet` stores each element into a single bit and packs 64 bits into a long, thereby using maximum efficeny. 2,147,483,648 bits only need `2,147,483,648/8` bytes to store them, which translates to 256MB of RAM - no problem in the current age where heap sizes of 64GB are not unheard of.

Comment: When I wrote that, I was referring to a different array, not the array in the BitSet itself. Maybe I should update my answer to make it more clear... other than that you are right! Thanks!

Comment: @schteppe imagine you have a file with  2^63 unique positive numbers. And you want to find out which number is missing. The one approach is to create a bitset and set every bit index to corresponding number. So in that case indexing via long (and not via int) is must-have feature. Moreover, every single modern language can store more that 2GiB array. But for some reason Java uses int for navigation.

Comment: Java: "long[] a = new long[2147483647]; " throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. JavaScript: "var a=[]; while(a.length<2147483647) a.push(a.length);" crashes Chrome. Both Rust and C++ fail if trying to allocate vectors of size 8*2147483647 bytes.

Comment: @schetteppe use JVM flags to allocate larger heap + maybe you just haven’t got enough RAM. On my side everything works perfectly. So the question stays the same: is it old quirk or we have some strong reasoning behind using int for indexing?